# Pandas: Aggregated and Group by - IDE: Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pandas-groupby, pandasql

**QQ - IDE: Pycharm - I am using the below Dataframe Sample format**

```
Name       Business        SegmentID   Revenue    Margin  OrderQuantity
James      Commercial      1001         1500      100     1
Joe        Consumer        1002         800       10      1
James      Commercial      1003         1900      110     2
James      Commercial      1004         1800      105     3
Samuel     Commercial      1005         1800      105     1
```

**I want to aggregated it in the below format**

```
Name      Revenue  Margin  OrderQuantity
James     5200     315     6
Joe       800      10      1
Samuel    1800     105     1
```

**What i have done so far ?**

Data import from pyodbc, passed to a pandas dataframe

```
df.groupby(['Name']).Revenue.sum().Margin.sum().OrderQuantity.sum()
```

I was Unable to get the desired output. is there something i need to be focusing on specifically while using pyodbc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groupby aggregate is what you are looking for:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['foo1','foo2','foo3','foo2','foo3'], 
'Business': ['bar2','bar3','bar1','bar1','bar1'],
    'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'Revenue':[10000,12500,7500,3000,15000],
    'Margin':[300,500,100,300,200],
    'Quanity':[1,2,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output of df:

```
 Business ID  Margin  Name  Quanity  Revenue                                                                           
0     bar2  1     300  foo1        1    10000                                                                           
1     bar3  2     500  foo2        2    12500                                                                           
2     bar1  3     100  foo3        2     7500                                                                           
3     bar1  4     300  foo2        3     3000                                                                           
4     bar1  5     200  foo3        4    15000
```

Then using groupby:

```
groupby_df_agg = df.groupby(['Name'])[('Revenue', 'Margin', 'Quanity')].agg(['sum'])

print(groupby_df_agg)
```

Output

```
     Revenue Margin Quanity                                                                                             
         sum    sum     sum                                                                                             
Name                                                                                                                    
foo1   10000    300       1                                                                                             
foo2   15500    800       5                                                                                             
foo3   22500    300       6
```

To extend by more categorical variables you can use:

```
groupby_df_agg = df.groupby(['Name','Business'])[('Revenue', 'Margin','Quanity')].agg(['sum'])
```

Output

```
              Revenue Margin                                                                                          
                  sum    sum                                                                                          
Name Business                                                                                                         
foo1 bar2       10000    300                                                                                          
foo2 bar1        3000    300                                                                                          
     bar3       12500    500                                                                                          
foo3 bar1       22500    300
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked beautify.. adding a QQ to it.. If i need to add another  column "Business" in the group by condition, it doesn't allow..

Comment: How did you try and add it?

Comment: groupby_df_agg = df.groupby(['Name', 'Business'])[('Revenue', 'Margin')].agg(['sum'])  is this rite ?

Comment: What python version are you using? I just added the code I used to add another categorical variable and the output. And can you describe what you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? Is it not giving you the desired output? Or is it an error message

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.1.. Now, this works fine.. there was an error with the column naming convention. Which i noticed.. The solution works now.. Thanks much for your help.. helped me understand it well...

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate method.

```
df.groupby(['Name']).agg({'Revenue':'sum, 'Margin': 'sum', 'OrderQuantity':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['James','Joe','James','James','Samuel'],
'Business': ['Commercial','Consumer','Commercial','Commercial','Commercial'],
    'Revenue':[1500,800,1900,1800,1800],
    'Margin':[100,10,110,105,105],
    'OrderQuanity':[1,1,2,3,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

groupby_df_agg = df.groupby(['Name','Business'])[('Revenue', 'Margin','OrderQuanity')].agg(['sum'])

print(groupby_df_agg)
```